# I'm having problems with Compiz

Tags: 14.04, compiz

I'll give you an example situation-I have two windows open of Program 1, and I'm currently active in Program 2. If I click on Program 1's icon in the launcher (it doesn't have to be pinned), the last window I was in while I used Program 1 comes up. But if I click the icon again to switch windows, while still in the window that came up, all of windows freeze for a couple seconds, then they all show up, stacked over one another (not like when you do <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>- which doesn't work either), without their window decorations, and then, after a couple seconds, the windows flicker,  disappear, and then they reappear, with their decorations.

Sometimes, if this happens too frequently (maybe two times in ten seconds), the second time, the windows do not regain their decorations, and it's stuck like that. If I have my terminal open, (sometimes this works) I can type in `compiz` and everything starts working again. If not, then I have to shut down my computer and lose all my work.

I tried `sudo apt-get install --reinstall compiz`, `sudo apt-get purge compiz`, and the same commands except with `unity` and `ubuntu-desktop` included in the reinstallation and purging.

I am literally afraid to use the launcher now because of this. Please help, I'll try anything but Ubuntu reinstallation by now.

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and Compiz 0.9.11.

Comment: Also, I occasionally can't use my keyboard, but I can use some menus within programs to close their windows to get to the desktop, where I can click on a compiz shortcut I put there to fix the problem.  The error I get whenever compiz crashes is "Segmentation fault".

Comment: Which compiz version do you have and which ubuntu version is it?

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and Compiz 0.9.11.

Comment: I have exactly same problem, same versions. Nvidia driver 340.32, 64 bit.